# is there an alternative to 'Out-Gridview" to display list?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am trying to check Active directory group memberships snf display them in a list not a grid.
Looking for alternative to Out-Gridview

```
""Get-ADUser –Identity Username_Here -Properties Name, memberof | select memberof | Out-GridView -Title 'Group Memberships'""
```

Comment: Please clarify what, specifically, you mean by _list_ (ideally, show an example) and Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: If you want to see the group memberships separaterd from each other you will have to use `Select-Obejct -ExpandProperty MemberOf`

Comment: Sorry for the formatting. When I use Out-GridView it displays all groups in a single row. I ned it to displayeach AD group on it's own row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `MemberOf` is an array. If you want to display its elements separated you have expand the array like this:

```
Get-ADUser –Identity 'Username_Here' -Properties Name, MemberOf | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf | 
        Out-GridView -Title 'Group Memberships'
```